# Is it possible to take a screenshot of a secondary Windows 10 desktop using Java?

Tags: windows-10, java, screenshot, multiple-desktop

If I want to take a screenshot of an extended desktop with multiple adapters/screens, I can use this code:

```
static void takeScreenShot(String path) throws AWTException, IOException {

    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (GraphicsDevice gd : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()) {
        screenRect = screenRect.union(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
    }
    BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);

    File output = new File(path);
    ImageIO.write(capture, "bmp", output);
}
```

But, in my case, I only have 1 VGA adapter (onboard), 1 monitor (HDMI) and I'm using the new Windows 10 virtual desktops feature.

[image: Windows10MultipleDesktops.png]

How do I take a screenshot of the other virtual desktop using a similar Java program?

I tried doubling the width of the `Rectangle` (1920x2), but from pixel 1920 to 3840, it's all black on the taken screenshot.

[image: BlackScreenShot.png]

```
static void takeScreenShot(String path) throws AWTException, IOException {

    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920*2, 1080);
    BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);

    File output = new File(path);
    ImageIO.write(capture, "bmp", output);
}
```

Comment: IIRC Virtual Desktops don’t really “exist”. They are accomplished by cleverly hiding and showing windows. You could also never screenshot anything off-screen.

Comment: Ok @DanielB.If you post the answer saying it's not possible with the above explanation i'll mark it as accepted.